# Birt report designer

Tags: report, birt, designer

I tried to establish one connection between BIRT and Oracle but it's not working. 
[image]

I received this error message :

[image]

Comment: Please ask in English https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Your driver must be something like : jdbc:oracle:thin:@prodHost:1521:ORCL

Answer (score 0):

First download an oracle JDBC driver from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html
take the `.jar` e.g. called `ojdbc8.jar`.

Then use use `Manage Divers...` menu and add the just downloaded `.jar`. This will add new entries to the driver dropdown menu. Now select the Oracle driver entry from the menu e.g. `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver (v12.2)`